# Requirements for Custom Journey Builder Activitity development

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, java, custom

I'm tasked with planning the development of a custom journey builder activity and have some questions:

1. **Can Java be used as the back-end for the developed webservice that will live in Journey Buider?** That would seem logical since the service needs to only receive data, but for the most part the documentation mentions PHP, .Net and server-side Javascript only. Would it not be problem to use with in conjunction with Postmonger?
2. **Is SSL really required to implement a custom activity?** Asking mostly if non-secure connections could be used in the pre-production phase - we would move the activity to a secure host when the tests are successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Java can absolutely be used to create the REST call for Journey Entry.

2: As far as I know SSL cannot be disabled but you can certainly try to pass it as an option...see here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glOZAAY

Answer (score 1):

You can use any language that you like. Typically when creating a custom activity the service will need to do more than just receive data. There are a number of configuration JSON and javascript files the Journey Builder will need to access on your server.

There is also the "front-end" aspect of the activity which is where a user would enter configuration details in Journey Builder via the drag and drop editor. This is also where the Postmonger part is utilised to send those configuration details to the Marketing Cloud server.

SSL is required for custom activities. Journey Builder will not work with non HTTPS connections so you will need to use HTTPS connections even for development phases.